# How to make Boostrap burger menu items displayed horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a Boostrap navbar. When we scale the page down, all of the navbar items collapse to the burger menu. Now, as expected, when we roll out the burger menu, the items are displayed in a "Burger" pattern, basically one under another. What I want to achieve is, to make the items, not displayed one under another, but one next to each other.
[Visually Explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xhAJ.png)
Does anyone know how to do this?
(I am using the normal navbar presets, from the boostrap website:)
Here is the code that I want to transform:

```
<nav id="mynavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img
            id="Logo"
            src="https://cdn.glitch.global/123df645-7c49-4cd3-b292-825ade4e767b/LogoTrimmedNewFont.png?v=1688645785034"
          />
        </a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
                <i class="bi bi-person-vcard"></i>
              </a>
              <h5 class="tooltiptext" style="text-align: left">
                Portfolio
              </h5>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <i class="bi bi-person-check"></i>
              </a>
              <h5 class="tooltiptext" style="text-align:">
                &nbsp; Hiring
              </h5>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <i class="bi bi-diagram-3"></i>
              </a>
              <h5 class="tooltiptext" style="text-align: left">
                &nbsp;&nbsp; Links
              </h5>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
              </a>
              <h5 class="tooltiptext" style="text-align:">
                &nbsp;Contact
              </h5>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I have already tried to set:

```
@media (max-width:768px){
    .navbar-nav{
      display: inline;
  }
    .navbar-nav li{
      display: inline;
  }
}
```

but with no success...

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Also please take the [tour] so you know how this site works. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `.navbar-nav` to `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`. Then add some padding/margins to `.navbar-nav li`

JS Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/vzeLwt62/

```css
  @media (max-width:768px) {
  ul.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row
  }
  .navbar-nav li {
    margin: 0 2rem
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/150x50/888888/EEE/Logo" alt="..." height="36">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="mt-4">Logo Nav by Start Bootstrap</h1>
  <p>The logo in the navbar is now a default Bootstrap feature in Bootstrap! Make sure to set the height of the logo within the HTML or using CSS. For best results, use an SVG image as your logo.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @isherwood it works for Bootstrap 5.2, the style is overwritten, maybe with how snippets add custom css and libraries? I updated the answer for the custome css to have stronger precedence (although not ideal, adding !important also works)

Comment: That looks better. However, you can achieve what you've done with custom CSS using Bootstrap classes, which is best practice. Try `flex-row`, and `px-4`. (`.navbar-nav` is already display flex.)

Answer (score 0):

You can give **flex-direction: row** to the **.navbar-nav** class.

But note that, due to css specificity, select the **class with the element ul**, otherwise bootstrap default css will override your flex-direction value.

Here is an example snippet:-

```css
ul.navbar-nav{
  flex-direction: row;
}

a.nav-link {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The snippet used is from the [boostrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `flex-row` Bootstrap class to the `.navbar-nav` list element to turn the flex container horizontal, then use padding classes to space things a bit.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/150x50/888888/EEE/Logo" alt="..." height="36">
    </a>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item px-2">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-2">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown px-2">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="mt-4">Logo Nav by Start Bootstrap</h1>
  <p>The logo in the navbar is now a default Bootstrap feature in Bootstrap! Make sure to set the height of the logo within the HTML or using CSS. For best results, use an SVG image as your logo.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```